# MVC4 VB.NET Multiple File Upload

Tags: vb.net, file-upload

I want to upload multiple files into my website onclick of submit.

I was able to achieve this partially. Multiple files are being uploaded in my website. But the problem is that i want different file uploads to upload files in different location using the same **Controller**

For eg

```
<form name="upload" id="upload" action="~/Home/MultiUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Filename: <input type="file" name="file1" /></label>
    <label>Filename: <input type="file" name="file2" /></label>
    <label>Filename: <input type="file" name="file3" /></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

From the above code, I want file1 to upload file to ~/App_Data/Uploads1, file2 to ~/App_Data/Uploads2 and file3 to ~/App_Data/Uploads3

Here is my code of the controller trying to save the files

```
Function MultiUpload(file As List(Of HttpPostedFileBase)) As ActionResult

    If (Not IsNothing(file)) Then
        For Each item As HttpPostedFileBase In file

            Dim filePath = IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), IO.Path.GetFileName(item.FileName))
            item.SaveAs(filePath)
        Next
    End If
Return RedirectToAction("Index")
End Function
```

As mentioned earlier, all the files are uploading files to the same location.

If uploading to different locations is somehow not possible, i would atleast want to track which filename is coming from which FileUpload

Thanks for your help
Very much appreciated